# NodeJS - How to get the HTTP header of a SOAP webservice's response

Tags: node.js, web-services, http, soap, http-headers

When consuming a SOAP webservice in NodeJS with the '`soap`' package. Like so:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};
clientsoap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

How do I get the HTTP header of the response to `MyFunction`? Specifically, I want the Cookie parameter inside the HTTP Header.

Is this something Node/Express can do? Or Is there another package I need to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The NodeJS soap module stores the last response headers against the client when invoking a method, so just access it in your callback:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://somewhere.com?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  client.myFunction(args, function(err, result) {
    console.log(client.lastResponseHeaders);        
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and have been working on it for a while now. I have made some progress to where I can see the cookies but they aren't coming through exactly as I expected. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or it's specific to the service WSDL I'm trying to hit. But here's my solution...

```
soap.createClient(pathOrUrlToWSDL, function(err, client) {
    client.myFunction(args, function(err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
        console.log(err, result, raw, soapHeader);
    });

    // -- should reach the response before the callback in client.myFunction()
    client.on('response', function(envelope, message) {
        // -- couldn't find documentation on this function, so I just named the variables 'envelope' and 'message'
        console.log(message.headers);
    });
});
```